# Environment variable not set, from Netbeans

Tags: c, netbeans

I am calling an external program from my c program in netbeans, where I had to set a environment variable!

I did that by using this command:

```
export MY_VARIABLE=/exampe/path/
```

And then I run the program from the command line and it works, but when I start netbeans and run it, he is still complaining that the MY_VARIABLE is not set..

Am I missing something here?? I have netbeans 8.0 and OSX System

Comment: What happens if you execute this command and then run Netbeans from the same terminal window?

Comment: Was hoping someone would explain how to set the env variables so they are usable for applications (like Netbeans)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CommandLine exports only last for the active session ..
That said, you have to make sure it's set when the program is running.

You can run:

```
// will set only if $MY_VARIABLE isn't set
system("[[ -n $MY_VARIABLE ]] || export MY_VARIABLE=/example/path");
```

or

```
// will set anyways
system("export MY_VARIABLE=/example/path");
```

to make sure it is set

Alternatively, if that didn't work, you can set the environment variable from within netbeans.

> Properties->Actions->Run Project->Set Properties: Add
>   Env.MY_VARIABLE=/example/path